# Concatenate two files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I concatenate http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16285637/video/out1.ts with http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16285637/video/out2.ts without too much quality loss ?

I have tried the following command, whose result is at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16285637/video/concatAll.mp4

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:out1.ts|out2.ts" -c copy -absf aac_adtstoasc concatAll.mp4
```

But the quality of the second file is massively altered. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output. For future reference you should ask `ffmpeg` command-line usage questions on [SU] since [SO] is strictly limited to programming discussions. Your question may be migrated, so no need to also post in [SU].